# Why was the same transaction executed twice?

Tags: transactions, extrinsic

The following 2 extrinsics :

- [10995944-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/10995944-2)
- [10996284-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/10996284-2)

were included in the blockchain, that shows that a transaction with exact same input parameters including the signature was executed twice. Why did this happened ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical case of **replaying an immortal transaction** since both mentioned extrinsics have an immortal lifetime.

[image: immortal lifetime]

Here are the steps that allowed this to happen :

The first extrinsic [10995944-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/event?extrinsic=10995944-2) was executed and it resulted in :

- Transferring successfully 4.98 DOT from the Sender to the Destination account as expected
- However, the amount that was withdrawn from the Sender account caused the balance of the account to drop below the existential deposit
- This resulted in the Sender account being **reaped**  ( [wiki-existential deposit](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#existential-deposit) & [ED - reaping](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-accounts#existential-deposit-and-reaping))
- Which implied that the nonce of the account was restarted to 0

> *If an account drops below the ED, it will be reaped, i.e. completely*
> *removed from storage and the nonce reset.*

What happened in the meantime (before we see the second extrinsic executed hence the same transaction executed again) is extrinsic [10996030-3](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/10996030-3) during which :

- The reaped account was funded again with 999.78 DOT
- So it became again active with nonce equals 0.

Hence the second extrinsic [10996284-2](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/10996284-2) could be validly submitted to the blockchain again.

This is an expected behavior since the **nonce** set in the extrinsic is again valid respect to the state of the blockchain. However this can be mitigated  by submitting mortal transactions as it is recommended in the [wiki-transaction mortality](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#transaction-mortality) :

> *NOTE: If an account is reaped and a user re-funds the account, then*
> *they could replay an immortal transaction. Always default to using a*
> *mortal extrinsic.*

Credits to the team that reported the case & Joe & Iker that provided extensive explanations to the team.